# SNMP subagent application crashes at init_agent()

Tags: c, linux, net-snmp, snmpd

I have implemented SNMP subagent functionality in my application using net-snmp library (http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/toolkit/demon/).

The application crashes at init_agent() call.
GDB-BackTrace for the same:

```
#0  0x00002b123483aaa1 in init_traps () from /usr/lib64/libnetsnmpagent.so.10
#1  0x00002b1234835cd0 in init_agent () from /usr/lib64/libnetsnmpagent.so.10
...
```

The error message at "/var/log/messages":

```
sample_app.exe[6642]: segfault at 0000000000659de0 rip 00002ac2749c2aa1 rsp 00007fff38c6ec48 error 7
```

I am using "NET-SNMP version: 5.3.2.2" on CentOS 5.5(elf5) 64Bit. The sample_app code is same as provided in tutorial(http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/toolkit/demon/example-demon.c)

The init_agent() is supposed to take config file name as argument, I have tried passing config file name which has 'correct configuration'/'incorrect configuration'/'file not present', In each case the application crashes with same error.

Please suggest any tools/links which will help me identify the actual cause of the crash. Any link for resolution of similar issue will also be helpful.

Thanks

---

Edit-
The issue has been resolved. The variable 'snmptrap_oid_len' was being declared/used in application's MIB C code, which is already part of net-snmp library 'agent_trap.c'. This was causing the conflict and hence crash.

PS: If you face similar issue, ensure that variables 'snmptrap_oid' and 'snmptrap_oid_len' are 'not redeclared'/'used correctly' in MIB C code.

Comment: Where does the crash happens in *your* code? What arguments are you passing to the library function? Are there any null or uninitialized pointers that should not be null or uninitialized? Just because the crash happens in a library function doesn't mean it's the actual fault of the function you call.

Comment: Crash happens when the application tries to initialize the snmp library. The argument I am passing is the name of application_configuration file e.g. "app_snmp_subagent", It refers to the file '/etc/snmp/app_snmp_subagent.conf'. I dont think there is any uninitialized pointers(will re verify) as the application runs correctly without SNMP subagent functionality.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to include the answer/solution, post it as an answer to your own question, and mark it as accepted.